# Any option to attach a dynamic Power Automate job to any newly created SharePoint list so that the job can transfer any changes to another global list

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

"Any option to attach any dynamic Power Automate job to a newly created SharePoint list so that the job can transfer any changes made in the current SharePoint to another global SharePoint list?"

As a beginner in Power Automate, I am facing a challenge.

**Scenario:**
Whenever a SharePoint Online site is created, an "Issues" list is automatically created based on the site template. I have created a Power Automate job that updates a global SharePoint list called "Global Issues" whenever there is a change in a specific "Issues" list.

**Problem:**
However, I cannot manually create the job every time a new SharePoint site is created. I am wondering if there is a way to attach the Power Automate job to a new "Issues" list when it is created so that it will be triggered to run whenever there is a change in the list.

Can you help me with this? Thank you very much.